# Arraylist keeps throwing IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arraylist, intervals

I am trying to build an interval tree. In this part I must take all the left endpoints in ascending order, and all the right endpoints in ascending order, and place them in a list of single points (no duplicates). However, I keep getting an indexOutOfBounds exceptions when I try to merge the right endpoints into the point list. I have ensured the capacity so that this doesn't happen, but it happens anyway. What am I not understanding here?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getSortedEndPoints(ArrayList<Interval> leftSortedIntervals, ArrayList<Interval> rightSortedIntervals) {

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < leftSortedIntervals.size() ; i++ ) {

        if (i >= 1 && leftSortedIntervals.get(i-1).leftEndPoint != leftSortedIntervals.get(i).leftEndPoint ) {
        result.add(leftSortedIntervals.get(i).leftEndPoint);
        }
        else if (i == 0) {

            result.add(leftSortedIntervals.get(i).leftEndPoint);

        }

    }
    result.ensureCapacity(rightSortedIntervals.size()*2);
    for (int j = 0 ; j < rightSortedIntervals.size(); j++) {
        boolean duplicate = false;
        int size = result.size()-1;
        int temp = rightSortedIntervals.get(j).rightEndPoint;
        while (size >= 0 && result.get(size) >= rightSortedIntervals.get(j).rightEndPoint ) {
            if (result.get(size) == rightSortedIntervals.get(j).rightEndPoint) {
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                result.set(size+1, result.get(size));

                size--;
            }


        }
        if (duplicate = true) {

            continue;

        }
        else {
        result.add(size, temp);
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
else {
            result.set(size+1, result.get(size));

            size--;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
int size = result.size() - 1;
// ...
result.set(size + 1, result.get(size));
size--;
```

Therefore the error will occur everytime: at the first iteration, `size + 1 == result.size()` so you cannot call `result.set(size+1, anything)`

Comment: Are you sure? Size is just an integer value (poor naming I know). Here I am really just moving everything over to the right to make room for the the endpoint I am inserting.

Comment: Yes I am sure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,E): IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

Answer (score 0):

ensureCapacity doesn't do what you think it does.

An ArrayList has two different values, size and capacity. Capacity is the amount of storage in the underlying array, but this is not exposed to the user. Size is the number of elements considered in the collection, and this is what matters when interacting with it.

The only reason the capacity functions exist is because if you know how many elements you want to use before hand, increasing the capacity lets you add elements without potentially slow array reallocations.